# SQLite query statements in separate file

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite

I'm developing an Android application and I would like to keep my SQLite query statements outside of my Java classes.

I considered using a *.properties* file, in which to store all of my SQL statements. Sounds fine, each property in a *.properties* file holds a string - I can even store prepared statements and give them the needed parameters, for example:

```
get.student.with.first.name=SELECT * FROM Students WHERE FirstName = ?;
```

However, I have also implemented Persistence Contracts for my database tables like so:

```
public final class StudentPersistenceContract {
    private StudentPersistenceContract() {}

    public static abstract class StudentEntry implements BaseColumns {
        public static final String TABLE_NAME = "Student";

        public static final String COLUMN_FIRST_NAME = "FirstName";
        public static final String COLUMN_LAST_NAME = "LastName";
    }
}
```

I wouldn't want to hardcode the table and column names into the entries of the *.properties* file, I would like to access them dynamically like so: StudentPersistenceContract.StudentEntry.TABLE_NAME, etc.

One thing I thought of was creating a class which can't be instantiated in which to "construct" the queries I need. Something along the lines of...

```
public final class SqlQueryConstructor {

    private SqlQueryConstructor() {}

    public static final String GET_STUDENT_WITH_FIRST_NAME = "SELECT * FROM " + StudentPersistenceContract.StudentEntry.TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + StudentPersistenceContract.StudentEntry.COLUMN_FIRST_NAME + " = ?;";
}
```

This way I can get the desired SQL query by accessing: SqlQueryConstructor.GET_STUDENT_WITH_FIRST_NAME

This is still a Java class, but it'll be good to know that all of my SQL is there and not scattered around all over the place.

Is this a good idea? Are there any other alternatives?

Comment: `I considered using a .properties file, in which to store all of my SQL statements. Sounds fine, each property in a .properties file holds a string` Why not using **strings.xml**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have decided to use my second approach - using a class with static fields for the SQLite statements. I read about when it's good to use strings.xml and when to use static final Strings: [android - strings.xml vs static constants](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16160047/android-strings-xml-vs-static-constants), [Android strings, Should I use strings.xml or java strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29170951/android-strings-should-i-use-strings-xml-or-java-strings), etc.

So I'll use strings.xml for localization and the class with static fields for the SQL statements.